# Unexpected token in meteor app but it needs to be there

Tags: meteor

I have this problem where it tells me that there is an unexpected token ":".

The thing is that it should be there as you will could see in the following code:

```
    Meteor.methods({
  addEvent:function(title, description, eventStart, eventEnd, city, country, road){
    if(!Meteor.userId()){
      throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }

     Events.insert({
       title: title,
       description: description,
       eventStart: eventStart,
       eventEnd: eventEnd,
       createdAt: new Date(),
       username: Meteor.user().username,
       owner: Meteor.userId(),
       address:{
         city: city,
         country: country,
         road: road
       }
     });
  },
  deleteEvent:function(eventId){
      var event = Events.findOne(eventId);

      if(event.private && event.owner){
        throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
      }
      Events.remove(eventId);
    }
  },
  updateEvent: function(eventId, title, description){
    var event = Events.findOne(eventId);

    if(event.owner !== Meteor.userId()){
      throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
    }

    Events.update(eventId, {$set: {title: title, description: description}});
  }
});
```

The token is the : betweeen updateEvent and function, which I would mean should be there no matter what.

Comment: It's probably something before that

Comment: Maybe `Meteor.Meteor.methods` ?

Comment: put a space after the :

Comment: Please update the post to include the whole function call.

Comment: @SteveFerg, u serious!? [RTFM](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.2)!

Comment: I deleted the extra Meteor that Atom added ... and have added all the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the extra brace inside the `deleteEvent` method.

```
  deleteEvent:function(eventId){
      var event = Events.findOne(eventId);

      if(event.private && event.owner){
        throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
      }
      Events.remove(eventId);
  },
```